# Архитектура приложения

Tags: android, android-fragment

В своем приложении я использую фрагменты, для бесшовного переключения между экранами. И все было хорошо, пока не появилась необходимость скрывать toolbar при прокрутке, я сделал это с помощью recyclerview и библиотеке material design, как тут показано https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/06/23/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scrolling(part3)/

Но теперь не могу вписать это в свою архитектуру.
У меня еще используется NavigationDrawer, и получается так что мне нужно разделить toolbar и NavigationDrawer но как тогда их связать я не знаю, как мне можно разделить вот такую верстку на фрагменты, что бы был основной шаблон и фрагменты просто вставлялись в контайнер в нем.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/toolbar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ToolbarPopup"
            style="@style/Widget.AppTheme.Toolbar.Solid"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="6dp"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:name="ru.vanicon.so.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"/>
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что именно у вас не получается. Не убирается Toolbar при прокрутке recyclerView во фрагменте?

Comment: Нет с этим все работает, проблема чисто архитектурного плана. Раньше я просто создавал один layout файл с DrawerLayout и toolbar'om внутри, и вставлял туда фрагменты какие нужны, а теперь верстка поменялась, и появился AppBarLayout, и я не могу разделить все это по фрагментам, из-за того что в него еще нужно вставить TabLayout который раньше был в отдельном фрагменте, а сейчас я не могу все это разделить, я понятно объяснил?